# Logo not showing in getSupportActionBar()

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to show logo/icon in header bar with getSupportActionBar(). I get just show text title.

In manifest i have add below:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:killAfterRestore="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/icon"
        android:theme="@style/mainStyle" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:logo="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

In style.xml

```
<style name="mainStyle" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

    <item name="displayOptions">showTitle|homeAsUp|useLogo</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle|homeAsUp|useLogo</item>
</style>
```

But not showing icon/logo. just showing text app name. what is wrong with my code?
I want to get show logo/icon in beside left appname and if click it go to back or go to home, like as Google Play App.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add showHome in displayOption and android:displayOptions it will work

UPDATE :

Simply avoid use displayOption in styles and add getSupportactionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); in activity. It Will also solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Dinesh solved, now icon is show, but if i click icon not go to back. before just "<+title", and now "<+icon+title" but i click it not go to  back.

Comment: you need to add getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); in to the specified activity